# VirtualBox .vdi file to BOOTABLE .iso

Tags: image, virtualbox, iso, dd, bootable

I saw a few solutions for that question but non of them was working for me.
My goal is (pretty obvious) to make a custom made OS and make it bootable from USB.

The solution must work for both Windows OS and Linox Based operating systems.

I have tried :
(***after converting the .vdi to .img)

```
sudo apt install iat
iat file.img file.iso
```

I have also tried to convert vmdk file with:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
qemu-img convert -f vmdk os.vmdk os.raw
dd if=os.raw of=os.iso status=progress
```

I does convert it to ISO but it's not bootable.

I want super clean solution without transfering the bootable part afterwards so it would be directly inside the original ISO file.

Thanks :D

Comment: I have also tried : VBoxManage clonehd heziGangina.vdi heziGangina.img --format RAW

Comment: ...and I also tried: VBoxManage clonehd heziGangina.vmdk heziGangina.iso --format VMDK

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS

First copy the .VDI file to C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

Then run the following command

```
CD C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
VBoxManage.exe clonehd --format VDI "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\FileName.vdi" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\NewImage.img"
```